# Inject in Pinia throws undifined

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I'm trying to impelement vue-gates from https://github.com/thonymg/vue-zo

Inject from vue is not giving the instance and throws undefined but when I inject it right in App.vue it works fine

Wondering if someone knows why this happen

```
import { inject } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useGatesStore = defineStore("api", () => {
  const $zo = inject("$zo");
  
  const setRoles = () => {
    console.log($zo)
  }

  return {
    setRoles
  };
})
```

Main.js

```
import './assets/base.scss'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createApp, markRaw } from 'vue'
import { router } from './router'
import { VueClipboard } from '@soerenmartius/vue3-clipboard'
import { VueZo } from 'vue-zo'

import Modal from "vue-bs-modal";
import progressBar from './includes/progress-bar';
import App from './App.vue'
import i18n from './includes/i18n'

import 'notyf/notyf.min.css';

import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores';

const pinia = createPinia();
pinia.use(({ store }) => { store.router = markRaw(router) });

const app = createApp(App)

app.config.errorHandler = () => null;
app.config.warnHandler = () => null;

app.use(pinia)

const authStore = useAuthStore();
authStore.attempt(localStorage.getItem('token')).then(() => 
{
    app.use(router)
    .use(i18n)
    .use(BootstrapVue)
    .use(Modal)
    .use(VueClipboard)
    .use(VueZo)
    .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
    .mount('#app')
    progressBar(router)
})
```

Comment: Send your `main.js`/`main.ts`

Comment: @BernardBorg i've posted it in a new answer. thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry! quite new to stackoverflow either. Added in main post and deleted the answer!

Comment: What is `authStore.attempt` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @BernardBorg store attempt is looking if the JWT token exists/valid once page is loaded.

Comment: No. This logic should be moved to your App.vue. Register your plugins (BootstrapVue,  VueZo, etc) before you do `app.use(pinia)`

Comment: @BernardBorg even when I register Vuezo as first element and before pinia its still returning undefined

Comment: What does "throws undifined" mean? If there's an error, please, list it. It's not shown where useGatesStore is used. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BernardBorg I tried to reproduce the situation but it works there for some reason... I think theres something faulty at my side. https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lichterman-2mqsho?file=/src/main.js

Comment: @BernardBorg I'm not using typescript

Comment: @BernardBorg any idea why the instance from $zo returns undefined on a click event? See example https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lichterman-2mqsho?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Inject does not seem to be meant to be called outside of components according to Vue's official documentation. You could probably just accept it as a parameter in the store function from the components anyways.

Comment: You can call inject outside a component but you have to bu dure that it is called before a component renders in the case of a component or that you call the `use` function of a store if its in a store